# How to retrieve data in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony

**UPDATE 2*

In my Symfony project,I have a table named 'satelliteImage'. In this table there are two attributes: latitude and longitude. I want to retrieve an entry using these two values.

```
/**
     * @Route("/displayByNumber/{latitude}/{longitude}", name="satellite_images_display_latlon")
     */
    public function displayByLatLonAction($latitude,$longitude)
    {
        $satelliteImage=$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:satelliteImage')
            ->findOneBy(array('latitude'=>$latitude,'longitude'=>$longitude));

        $picture=base64_encode(stream_get_contents($satelliteImage->getImage()));

        return $this->render('satelliteImages/display.html.twig',array(
            'satelliteImage' => $satelliteImage,
            'picture'=>$picture
        ));

    }
```

eg :-  latitude=6.43435564545, longitude=78.456575545

I want to retrieve all the entries whose latitude and longitude are less than above values. I tried this but it returns nothing

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('image')
            ->where('image.latitude< :nelatitude')
            ->andWhere('image.longitude< :nelongitude')


            ->setParameters(array(
                'nelatitude'=> $nelatitude,
                'nelongitude'=> $nelongitude,

            ))
            //->orderBy('p.price', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Don't use `%` if it is not a `LIKE` query. You need to study basic sql.

Comment: @goto I updated it, but still get no value. Can I give a float or do I need to convert it to string?

Comment: The query looks ok, are you sure you have good data in your database?

Comment: @goto It worked, I had mistakenly interchanged latitude with longitude.....Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:satelliteImage');
    $satelliteImage = $qb->createQueryBuilder('s')
           ->where('s.latitude LIKE :latitude')
           ->orWhere('s.longitude LIKE :longitude')
           ->setParameter('latitude', $latitude. '%')
           ->setParameter('longitude', $longitude. '%')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

If you want to find records which must be started with same values for both of the parameters latitude and longtitude. You should replace orWhere with andWhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I updated my question. If you have knowledge on Doctrine query language can you give me a help

Answer (score 0):

Are latitude and longitude stored as floats?

Than I'd try:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$sImage = $qb->select('image')
             ->from('AppBundle:satelliteImage', 'image')
             ->where($qb->expr()->lt('image.longitude', ':lon'))
             ->andWhere($qb->expr()->lt('image.latitude', ':lat'))
             ->getQuery()
             ->setParameter('lon', $longitude)
             ->setParameter('lat', $latitude)
             ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Assuming you provide $latitude and $longitude also as floats.